# Coypu using InternetExplorerOptions

Tags: coypu

I've been developing automation using Selenium and InternetExplorerDriver for a while. I want to move to Coypu and I'm trying to convert my code. In Selenium I would specify:

```
InternetExplorerOptions customProfile = new InternetExplorerOptions()
{
  EnsureCleanSession = true,
  EnableNativeEvents = false,
  IgnoreZoomLevel = true,
  IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
  RequireWindowFocus = false,
  EnablePersistentHover = false,
  AcceptInsecureCertificates = true,
};
InternetExplorerDriver customDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(customProfile);
```

Is there any way to use these settings with Coypu?

When I try to pass in the customDriver in the code sample above by doing:

```
browserSession = new BrowserSession(session, customDriver);
```

it complains that "Cannot convert from 'OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver' to 'Coypu.Driver'

Is there some way to make the BrowserSession take the InternetExplorerDriver as a parameter? Or is there some way to specify the settings in the customProfile in the Coypu version of the SeleniumWebDriver?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own subclass of `Coypu.Drivers.Selenium.SeleniumWebDriver`. `SeleniumWebDriver` does have a protected constructor, taking an `OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver` as first argument.

Using the snippets you've provided, this would lead to the following code:

```cs
public class MySeleniumWebDriver : SeleniumWebDriver
{
    public MySeleniumWebDriver(IWebDriver webDriver, Browser browser)
        : base(webDriver, browser)
    {
    }
}
```

```cs
var internetExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions()
{
    EnsureCleanSession = true,
    EnableNativeEvents = false,
    IgnoreZoomLevel = true,
    IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
    RequireWindowFocus = false,
    EnablePersistentHover = false,
    AcceptInsecureCertificates = true,
};
var internetExplorerDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(internetExplorerOptions);

var myDriver = new MySeleniumWebDriver(internetExplorerDriver, Browser.InternetExplorer);

var browserSession = new BrowserSession(session, myDriver);
```